# How to assign string to NSDictionary using for loop?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdictionary

So, I retrieve song info using mpmediapicker on my application. I want to assign song info to dictionary so it's easy to populate it to tableview. But I found trouble when assigning value to dictionary on for loop.

Here is my code:

```
for thisItem in mediaItemCollection!.items as! [MPMediaItem]{

        let itemUrl = thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL)
            as? NSURL

        let itemTitle =
        thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
            as? String

        let itemArtist =
        thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist)
            as? String

        let itemArtwork =
        thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork)
            as? MPMediaItemArtwork


        playlist = ["title" : itemTitle! , "artist" : itemArtist!, "song_url" : itemUrl!]


    }
```

and below is what I got:

```
Optional({
    artist = "ASKING ALEXANDRIA";
    "song_url" = "ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=5357233978197423496";
    title = Alerion;
})
```

it's only retrieving the last song. How can I fix this problem ?

the format I want is like below:

```
Optional({artist = "ASKING ALEXANDRIA";"song_url" = "ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=5357233978197423496";title = Alerion;}, {artist = "ASKING ALEXANDRIA";"song_url" = "ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=5357239348197423496"; title = The Prophecy;}, {artist = "ASKING ALEXANDRIA";"song_url" = "ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=53572339781974234123";title = Breathless;})
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong playlist is a `NSDictionary`

You have to create an `NSMutableArray`

```
var playlistArray : NSMutableArray = []
```

Now add the `playlist` in to array inside for loop.

```
playlistArray.addObject(playlist)
```

Print after completing the loop

```
println("\(playlistArray)")
```

Comment: Welcome anytime @EgaSetyaPutra

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending new data to the array you are just making the array equals the values

Try this:

```
playlist += ["title" : itemTitle! , "artist" : itemArtist!, "song_url" : itemUrl!]
```

or

```
playlist.append(["title" : itemTitle! , "artist" : itemArtist!, "song_url" : itemUrl!])
```

Assuming your playlist is an array of dictionaries that can be created like:

```
var playlist : [Dictionary<String, Int>] = []
```

or

```
var playlist = [Dictionary<String, Int>]()
```

or

```
var playlist : [[String:Int]] = []
```

or

```
var playlist = [[String:Int]]()
```